# jQuery extension works with jQuery 1.4.4 but not 1.7.2

Tags: jquery

I have the requirement to produce a really nice-looking drop-down form element based on an HTML select.  The best (most appropriate for this project) I've been able to find is this one: http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/11/better-select-jquery-css3/select-jquery.html.  It works by replacing the HTML elements with custom mark-up which is nicely styled and animated.  All good.

However, it doesn't work with the newer versions of jQuery.  I've set up a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VTTyu/ which shows what it does.  It works great with jQuery 1.4.4 but when you change it to use jQuery 1.7.2 (which I'm using elsewhere in my project) it stops working.

I know I can read through the release notes of each jQuery release for the past 18 months and try to establish what might have changed to cause this, but I wondered if anyone more experienced could identify the problem?

Any pointers/suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks folks.

EDIT: with some more testing on fiddle it seems to work with jQuery up to 1.5.2, but any version after that and the drop-down button just disappears from the page.

Comment: Works fine for me (apart from images 404ing), what's your problem?

Comment: Images fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/VTTyu/1/

Comment: When I select jquery 1.7.2 and run it, the button just disappears from the page.  It's the same in my project and in this fiddle (so I don't think it's anything specific to my project - I really just think there's an incompatibility between the function and jquery 1.7.2).  I'm using Chrome 21.0.1180.89 m and Firefox 14.0.1.

Comment: Oh, I see, I had falsely assumed your jsfiddle was the bugged one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace (twice) `className` with `'class'` (quotes too) and see the magic happen.

Comment: together with the change from .attr to .prop I would give a +1

Answer (score 3):

The use of `attr` was changed, so

```
select.attr('selectedIndex')
```

will not work beyond 1.6, instead;

```
select.prop('selectedIndex')
```

See comments on [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: together with the change from className to 'class' I would give a +1 :-)

Comment: Both of these improve it.  Still though, the dropdown appears over the original button when clicked though, which it doesn't do in v1.4.4, so there must still be something else awry...

Comment: @Dan go ahead and combine it with the answer from jerone et voilà

Comment: @Dan fixing className here `var dropDown = $('<ul>',{class:'dropDown'});` should fix it as @jerone stated

Comment: @Dan be careful to wrap the 'class' in quotes because class is a reserved keyword in Javascript (for whatever reason)

Comment: You're right - there are two instances of className which needed replacing, I was only doing one.  Fixed!  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

the `.attr()` doesnot supports getting DOM object properties anymore since jQuery 1.6. So use the `.prop()` method instead like in this line `if(i==select.prop('selectedIndex')){ }`

[see this update on `.attr()`](http://ejohn.org/blog/jquery-16-and-attr/)